# Angular2 - polyfills.bundle.js long CPU time

Tags: angular, webpack

The page first loading is too long(more than 40s) and profiling info shows a long and looped CPU call: ZoneTask.invoke > ..... > JitCompiler._compileComponents

The project is running based on `https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter`

What points should I focus on to optimise the loading stage?